# How much influence do individual professor have on grad admissions?

Tags: graduate-admissions, career-path, professorship, supervision

Say I have emailed a professor a few times, and told him I would like to work with him for my PhD etc. and that professor is interested:

How much of a factor could this possibly be in my application?

What about the (not so exact) opposite: somebody in the department doesn't like me, I apply there to work with somebody else etc.?